# How to make a row appear several times depending on a value in a column?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm creating a dataset for users eligible to win a raffle. All registered users are eligible, however premium users get 2 tickets to enter instead of 1. If I have a table like below:

```
user_id     type
16234       premium
19273       regular
13846       regular
22343       regular
28820       premium
```

How do i get it to print:

```
user_id
16234
16234
19273
13846
22343
28820
28820
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a "BigQuery"ish way of expressing the logic:

```
SELECT u_id
FROM (SELECT 16234 as user_id, 'premium' as type UNION ALL
      SELECT 19273, 'regular'
     ) t JOIN
     UNNEST(ARRAY[t.user_id, t.user_id]) u_id with offset n
     ON n = 1 or type = 'premium';
```

Or like this:

```
SELECT t.user_id
FROM (SELECT 16234 as user_id, 'premium' as type UNION ALL
      SELECT 19273, 'regular'
     ) t CROSS JOIN
     UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, (CASE WHEN type = 'premium' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END))) n;
```

The advantage of this approach over something like `UNION ALL` is that it generalizes quite easily.  For instance, if premium users got 20 tickets but regulars only got 5, this would be simpler to implement.

Answer (score 2):

you can select all and then union the premium users:

```
(select user_id from my_table) union all
(select user_id from my_table where type='premium')
```